# Nested index route not rendering in outlet properly

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to render `taking-cash/index` inside `taking-cash`'s `{{outlet}}`:

[image]

`router.js`:

```
  this.route('retirement-options', function () {
    this.route('taking-cash');
```

It doesn't render it inside the outlet, unless I explicitly specify the `/index` path:

```
  this.route('retirement-options', function () {
    this.route('taking-cash', function() {
      this.route('index', { path: '' });
    });
  });
```

Why isn't `/index` implied, can I not specify it in `router.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember will provide an index route automatically only for routes indeed, but it does not need to have a child specifically. It is actually the callback function that has to be present.

So looking at the example,

```js
this.route('retirement-options', function() {
  this.route('taking-cash', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '' });
  });
});
```

the index part is not mandatory specifically. As soon as you have a callback function declared, the index will be there.

This would do exactly the same as the example above.

```js
this.route('retirement-options', function() {
  this.route('taking-cash', function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ember provides an index route automatically only for routes, which have at least one other child.

Let's have a look at your example:

```js
  this.route('retirement-options', function () {
    this.route('taking-cash');
  });
```

This creates three routes:

- `retirement-options`
- `retirement-options.index`
- `retirement-options.taking-cash`

`retirement-options.index` and `retirement-options.taking-cash` both share the same parent route `retirement-options`.

`retirement-options` is not navigateable itself. It will always resolve to the `retirement-options.index` route unless transition targets `taking-cash` child route explicitly.

As soon as you add another child route to `retirement-options.taking-cash` an index route will be created for it automatically by Ember.

You can enforce an explicit index route by creating a route as you have shown. But there is not much value of having an index route as only leaf node.

Please find more information about the *Index Routes* in the guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes